# Hide content behind an image

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying a small code that has a div with image as a background and there is some text in it.

Here the case is when the user clicks on the `div`, the background should become white(and it is working perfectly). But Initially, the text that is present should be behind the Image. More like a foreground image.

Here is a working fiddle. https://jsfiddle.net/rj0h1g16/

please let me know where am I going wrong and how can I fix this.

Thanks

Comment: Do you want to know how to hide the text on init?

Answer (score 0):

You could do this by initially setting the text opacity to 0 and changing its color to black with the same click event

```js
function remove_image() {
  document.getElementById("myClass").style.background = "white";
  document.getElementById("myClass").style.color = "black";
}
```

```css
.myClass {
  background: url("https://cdn2.droom.in/photos/images/drm/super-cars.png");
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}
```

```html
<div class="myClass" id="myClass" onclick="remove_image()">
  This is texr
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could simply set the display style on the text from "none" to anything else as you click.

```
<div class="myClass" id="myClass" onclick="remove_image()">
   <div class="myText" id="myText"> This is texr</div> 
</div>

function remove_image() {
  document.getElementById("myClass").style.background = "white";
  document.getElementById("myText").style.display = "inline";
}

.myClass {
  background: url("https://cdn2.droom.in/photos/images/drm/super-cars.png");
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px
}
.myText {
  display: none;
}
```

See here: https://jsfiddle.net/hg748zk7/

Answer (score 0):

> I want the text behind the image

You can use the `z-index` property for that. But the text will need to be wrapped in a new element.

In the example I've used js to add a class with the new properties you want.

```js
function remove_image() {
  document.getElementById("myClass").classList.add('active');
}
```

```css
.myClass {
  background: url("https://cdn2.droom.in/photos/images/drm/super-cars.png");
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px
}

.myClass.active {
  background: white;
}

span {
  z-index: -1;
  position: relative;
}

.myClass.active span {
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="myClass" id="myClass" onclick="remove_image()">
  <span>This is text</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function remove_image() {
  document.getElementById("myClass").style.background = "white";
  document.getElementsByTagName('span')[0].style.display = 'block'
}
```

```css
.myClass {
  background: url("https://cdn2.droom.in/photos/images/drm/super-cars.png");
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div  class="myClass" id="myClass" onclick="remove_image()">
 <span style='display:none;'>This is texr </span>
</div>
```